# get single object with http get request in Angular with rxjs

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I am currently trying to implement a function on my website where, upon entering the id of an object, the referenced object is displayed.

I am able to get and display Observable for use in the `*ngFor` for example but even a single element gets returned as an observable and I don't know how to convert it into an object of known type. Most guides or answers in the internet reference older versions of Rxjs using `.json` or other deprecated functions.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
getArticleById (id : string){
  let geturl = "http://localhost:8080/api/article_index/id/" + id;
  this.temp = this.http.get<article>(geturl);


  console.log(this.temp);       //prints "undefined"
  return this.temp;
}
```

I*ll try to answer questions and try advice as soon as possible.

I changed it to this code, as suggested:

```
  getArticleById(id : string){
let geturl = "http://localhost:8080/api/article_index/id/" + id;
this.http.get<article>(geturl).subscribe( result => 
  {
      console.log(result);
      this.temp = result;
  })
  return this.temp;
```

}

The log still says "undefined".

This is what I get via postman:

```
{
"tags": [
    "[Fritz,Leslie.Heidenreich39,Feest]"
],
"_id": "5f39483596a8b31e70bb68cb",
"headline": "Use the 1080p TCP circuit, then you can transmit the solid state capacitor!",
"timestamp": "98.36.29",
"region": "Puerto Rico",
"createdAt": "2020-08-16T14:52:37.943Z",
"updatedAt": "2020-08-16T14:52:37.943Z",
"__v": 0  }
```

Comment: You need to subscribe.

Comment: when subscribed, I get an "Subscriber" Element logged to the console - what then? I want a object of custom type "article"

Comment: can you add a stackblitz ?

Comment: here is demo how to make ```HTTP``` request https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-http-response-with-status-code

Comment: Thank you for the demo - I think I understoof how it is supposed to work - but I always get an `Object`, not the `article` I need.

Comment: I can't even access the `.body` attribute of the response if I remove the `<article>` cast - why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how httpClient functions and how you do communication with your backend: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server

So in your case it would be something like:

in a service:

```
getArticleById(id : string) {
  let geturl = "http://localhost:8080/api/article_index/id/" + id;
  return this.http.get<article>(geturl);
};
```

in a component that needs data:

```
...
this.backendService.getArticleById(id).subscribe( result => console.log(result) )
```

If you just want to do it without separation like the above you can do it like so:

```
getArticleById (id : string){
  let geturl = "http://localhost:8080/api/article_index/id/" + id;
  this.http.get<article>(geturl).subscribe( result => 
      {
          console.log(result);
          this.temp = result;
      })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look into my issue. Sadly the console still says "undefined"

Comment: what does your api return if you would poke it via curl or Postman?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: can you also add exactly what curl you use with Postman?

Comment: what do you mean? I used a get request: this one for example: `http://localhost:8080/api/article_index/id/5f39483596a8b31e70bb68cb`

Comment: okay, I solved the problem - I'll post the answer in a moment